# probability question of paper class 11

Tags: probability

In a box there are 2 red, 3 black and 4 white balls.Out of these three are drawn together.The probability of these being of same colour is what
a. 1/84
b.1/21
c.5/84
d.3/21

well i'm bit confused about counting red balls in or what also plz explain the solution thanks also please give an answer within 12 hrs please its a hurry

Comment: There are 2 ways to get 3 balls of the same colour. Either all black or all white. The answer P(3 black) + P(3 white)

Comment: so what will be the answer? i think u told me the cases so yeah 2 cases are possible but how to find probability

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom93=84$ ways to pick 3 balls out of 9. All 3 must be black or white in order to be of the same colour. There is $\binom33=1$ way to pick all 3 black balls out of 3 and there are $\binom43=4$ ways to pick all 3 white balls out of 4. Thus, the probability is $\dfrac{1+4}{84}=\dfrac{5}{84}$.

Comment: Thanks secondly, can u tell me the way like to differ when to multiply or add the probabilities